# Regex to identify bracketless if statements

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression to detect bracketless if statements in Javascript from traditional if statements.

I'm trying to detect statements such as this one:

```
if (foo) doSomething();
```

without detecting the following statement:

```
if (foo) {
    doSomething();
}
```

So far I've come up with the following expression: `if(\s*)\(.*\)\s(?!{)` which allows me to detect most of the bracketless if statements insensitive to spaces between the `if` and the condition.

However this expression is also triggered for statements like the following bacause of the closing parenthesis of the function call:

```
if (foo()) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Is there anyway to prevent this happening or is it fundamentally impossible?

Comment: You'd probably better use an existing javascript parser, but to solve your immediate problem you could match `if[^{]*$`. This will match if with multi-line conditions too though, which your current regex also did anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like [`/if.*\)\s*(?!\{)\s*\n\s*(?!\{)/gm`](https://regexr.com/4ci19)

Of course it'd still match within strings, JSX, and so on